# Allow load balanced instances to connect single compute instance postgresql server

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling

I am looking for GCP networking best practice, where I can allow connection of auto-scaled instances to Postgresql server installed on separate instance.

So far I tried whitelisting load-balancer IP within firewall and postgresql config file, but failed.

Any help or pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load-balancer doesn't process information by itself, it just redirects Frontend addresse(s) and manage the requests with `Instance Groups`.

That instance group should manage the HTTP requests and connect with the database instance.

The load-balancer is used to dynamically distribute (or even create additional instances) to handle the requests over the same Frontend address.

--

So first you should make it work with a regular instance, configure it and save the *instance template*.  Then you can proceed with creating an instance group that can be managed by a load-balancer.

**EDIT** - *Extended the answer from my comment*

"I don't think your problem is related to Google cloud platform now. If you have a known IP address for the PostgreSQL server (connect using an internal network IP address so it doesn't change), then make sure your auto-balanced instances are in the same internal network, use db's internal IP and connect to it."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With single Instance I have no problem with connecting to different instance with Postgresql. My problem lies with the fact that, due to auto-balancer, if the IP addresses are not known in advance, what should be my approach to connect to the Postgresql db (within Instance).

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to google cloud platform now. If you have a known IP address for the Postgreesql server (connect using an internal network IP address so it doesn't change), then make sure your auto-balanced instances are in the same internal network, use db's internal IP and connect to it.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, I never thought about using internal IPs. Observing the firewalls, it seemed VMs with the internal IPs were allowed to communicate. Finally using internal IP it worked, though I had to allow all connections from postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf config files.

Comment: Glad I could help, edited the answer to include what worked for you, if you could mark as answer that would be apprecianted